# Overlap/hit test in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Im trying to get a hit test/overlap test to work in the below code which creates 200 circles in a random position on a canvas.  I am trying to store the positions of the circles in an array and then checking that array each time another circle is created in the for loop, if the randomly created x and y is too close to a already created circle it should keep getting a new random x and y until it isnt too close to an already created circle.

I just cant get it too work in the while loop.

Any help please...

Thanks

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", canvasDraw);


    function canvasDraw () {
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;

    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width, c.height);
    var abc = 0;

    var colours = new Array ("rgb(0,100,0)", "rgb(51,102,255)");
    var positions = new Array();


    function hitTest(x, y) {
    for(var p in positions) {
            pp = p.split(",");
        pp[0] = parseInt(pp[0]);
        pp[1] = parseInt(pp[1]);

        if(((x > (pp[0] - 24)) && (x < (pp[0] + 24))) && ((y > (pp[1] - 24)) && (y < (pp[1] + 24)))) {

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


            //Loop 200 times for 200 circles
    for (i=0; i<200; i++) {

        var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*c.width);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*c.height);

        while(hitTest(x, y) == true){
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*c.width);
            var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*c.height);
        }

        var pos = x.toString() + "," + y.toString();
        positions.push(pos);

        var radius = 10;
        var r = radius.toString();

        var b = colours[Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length)];

        circle(ctx,x,y, radius, b);

    }   
   }



    function circle (ctx, x, y, radius, b) {
  ctx.fillStyle = b;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
   }
  </script>
```

Comment: Will your circles always be the same radius, always?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things before beginning:

1. Don't create arrays with `new Array()`, unless you specify the initial length. Use `[]`;
2. Don't iterate through arrays using `for...in`: use a standard `for` with a counter. This is more a good practice;
3. Converting numbers into strings and converting back to numbers is useless and expensive. Use a small array to store both values;
4. Don't use "magic numbers", i.e. number with a precise value but hard to recognize immediately. Use named "constants" or put a comment near each of them telling what they mean, for future maintenance.

Ok, let's see the code.

```
if(((x > (pp[0] - 24)) && (x < (pp[0] + 24))) && ((y > (pp[1] - 24)) && (y < (pp[1] + 24))))
```

Honestly, what is this? I'd call it a cranky and obscure snippet. Recall what you've learnt at school:

```
var dx = pp[0] - x, dy = pp[1] - y;
if (dx * dx + dy * dy < 400) return true;
```

Isn't it much clearer?

Let's see the whole function:

```
function canvasDraw () {
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;

    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width, c.height);
    // Lolwut?
    // var abc = 0;

    var colours = ["rgb(0,100,0)", "rgb(51,102,255)"];
    var positions = [];


    function hitTest(x, y) {
        for (var j = 0; j < positions.length; j++) {
            var pp = positions[j];
            var dx = pp[0] - x, dy = pp[1] - y;
            if (dx * dx + dy * dy < 400) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    // You declare the radius once and for all
    var radius = 10;
    // Declare the local scoped variables. You forgot i
    var x, y, i;
    for (i=0; i<200; i++) {

        // How about a do...while instead of a while?
        do {
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*c.width);
            var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*c.height);
        // Testing with === is faster, always do it if you know the type
        // I'll let it here, but if the type is boolean, you can avoid testing
        // at all, as in while (hitTest(x, y));
        } while (hitTest(x, y) === true);

        positions.push([x, y]);

        // This instruction is useless
        // var r = radius.toString();

        var b = colours[Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length)];

        circle(ctx,x,y, radius, b);

    }   
}
```

**BEWARE**, though, that depending on your canvas size, there could be no more room for another circle, so it could end in an infinite loop. Try to put 200 circles with a radius of 10 inside a 40x40 box...
There should be another test to do, and *that* could be complicated.

Comment: +1 especially for testing against the distance-squared instead of involving an unnecessary call to `Math.sqrt`.

Comment: @Phrogz Yeah, thanks, but after all those words against magic numbers I used a magic number myself *cough*... Oh well, I'll let Rob A add a comment near that line :)

Comment: :) I'm slowly developing a rule of thumb that (when pushed to the extreme) says that the presence of any numeric literal (other than 0 or 1) or string literal (other than something matching portions of hardcoded property names) in the body of code is a sign of future bugs and/or refactoring that should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for this.  They still overlap though on a big canvas with plently of space for 200 circles and I cant see where its not working.

Comment: @RobA I do. The test should be `< 400` (20 squared) because two non-overlapping circle must be at least 20 apart. Fixed the code, sorry.

Comment: Glad to know that. If that works, upvote and put the check mark under the vote counter, on the top of the answer. Remember to do so for all the answers you like and fix you problems here on Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: Cant upvote until i have a higher reputation, checked the box though.

Comment: Aw snap! There, I upvoted your question so you have a little more reputation. But I noticed you asked another question, don't forget to check the answer there too.

Comment: it is good practice to say "better practice" instead of "more good practice"

Comment: @WKx I said "more a good practice", not "a more good practice" ;)